# State is not getting initialized to the initial state of reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to the react redux . Here, what I am doing is ,

```
const initialState = {
        Low: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                level: 'EASY'
            }
        ],
        Medium: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                level: 'MEDIUM'
            }
        ],
        High: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 0,
                technology: '',
                level: 'TOUGH'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now,In my reducer ,

```
 export default function QuizData(state = initialState, action) {
        switch (action.type) {
            case QUIZ_DATA:
                return {
                    ...state,
                    Low: action.data,
                    error: false,
                } 
            case RESET_QUIZ_CRITERIA: {
            console.log("intial state is ",  ...state);
            return {
                ...state
            }
```

Now, here what happens is after some manipulations, this objects gets changes with every key is having some values. like,

So, This gets changed.

```
{
        Low: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 11,
                technology: 'xsxs',
                level: 'EASY'
            }
        ],
        Medium: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 22,
                technology: 'swwsw',
                level: 'MEDIUM'
            }
        ],
        High: [
            {
                id: 0,
                technologyId: 110,
                technology: 'xsxsx',
                level: 'TOUGH'
            }
        ]
    }
```

for resetting my action is like ,

```
export function resetPreviousQuizSelectionCriteria() {
  console.log("Calling this");
  return {
    type: RESET_QUIZ_CRITERIA
  }
}
```

Now, what I want to do is that ,

When user clicks a button that time I want to change this to the initial state.

So that it will not have any values as it should be same as by default.

So, Can any one one suggest me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think returning initial State should resolve the issue.

```
 case RESET_QUIZ_CRITERIA: {
        console.log("intial state is ",  ...state);
        return {
            ...initialState
        }
```

try this if it works.

Comment: I actually tried this. But it does not work.It also has the same data

Comment: When I console log the default state that time it also has the same value.State itself has that values

Comment: initialState is const, it will never have values manipulated ones at any point of time. Only possibility is that action is not dispatched.

Comment: Are you able to see console of this line : console.log("intial state is ",  ...state); ?  put like this : console.log("intial state is ",  JSON.stringify(state));

Comment: Yes it is printing the data . but that data has the selcted values

Comment: Yes it will have selected values. Install redux dev tools and check if dispatch is fired and whats the state values. Thats the only option. Code wise it looks all good.

Comment: Hi I have checked this using devtools. Action is firing the reducer but it says in diff states are equal. Values are same there